# How to check rectangle collision on a line

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I have a line drawn from two rectangles, spanning from `xpos, ypos` to `xpos2, ypos2`. I'm trying to detect if a rectangle (stored in 4 arrays of X/Y pos and random speed in those two directions) collides with the line.

I've tried `(Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(xpos + 13, ypos + 13), new Vector2(EnX[index], EnY[index])) + Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(xpos2 + 13, ypos2 + 13), new Vector2(EnX[index], EnY[index])) == Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(xpos + 13, ypos + 13), new Vector2(xpos2 + 13, ypos2 + 13)))` in a `if` statement, but that doesn't work.

**EDIT:** I've now tried

```
        m = (ypos2 + 13 - ypos + 13) / (xpos2 + 13 - xpos + 13);
        b = ((m * xpos2 + 13) - ypos2 + 13);
        if (EnY[index] == m * EnX[index] + b)
```

Where Xpos/2 and ypos/2 are the line starting points. EnX[] and EnY[] are the "enemy" X and Y positions, where I'm trying to check if they're hitting a line.

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have the rectangle's corner positions as 2d vectors:

```
Vector2[] corners;
```

The rectangle intersects with the line if any two corner points lie on the opposite side of the line. To evaluate the side, we need the line's normal (the slope approach you tried may fail for vertical lines):

```
Vector2 normal = new Vector2D(ypos2 - ypos, xpos - xpos2);
```

We can then use the sign of the dot product to evaluate the side:

```
Vector2 lineStart = new Vector2(xpos, ypos);
//we don't know yet on which side of the line the rectangle lies
float rectangleSide = 0;
foreach(Vector2 corner in corners)
{
    //cornerSide will be positive if the corner is on the side the normal points to,
    //zero if the corner is exactly on the line, and negative otherwise
    float cornerSide = Vector2.Dot(corner - lineStart, normal);
    if(rectangleSide == 0)
        //first evaluated corner or all previous corners lie exactly on the line
        rectangleSide = cornerSide;
    else
        if(cornerSide != 0 && //ignore corners on the line
          (cornerSide > 0) != (rectangleSide > 0)) //different sides
             return true; //rectangle intersects with line
}
return false; //rectangle does not intersect with line
```